# How is "eff and blind" used?

Tags: british-english, idiom-meaning

A crossword clue in the Times 2 Jumbo Crossword Book—an assemblage of crosswords published in the Times—reads "use obscene language". The answer given is "eff and blind", confirmed by the [entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eff-and-blind) in the [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/) which is used as the authority for the crossword.

I'm a native (Australian) English speaker but the answer doesn't make any sense to me. An Australian driver might shout "Are you effing blind?" when another driver cuts across their path, but how is "eff and blind" actually used? The dictionary entry implies that the phrase is somehow the infinitive form of a verb ... but how is it used?

Comment: Notably (related to a US crossword) I'm an American and have never heard the phrase before now.  So it's not just because you're from Australia

Answer (score 12):

You might say something like "Then he burst into the house, effing and blinding." As the dictionary suggests, it is a verb (or a verb phrase). It refers to swearing in general, without actually saying what words were said. "Effing" is from "fuck" (i.e. "the eff word"), whereas "blinding" is from swear words such as "cor blimey" (i.e. "God blind me"), but the actual swear words used could be anything. The general idea is that someone is using a lot of swear words - consider it similar to someone "cursing/swearing a blue streak".

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the meaning is? Such as how is it distinct from 'effing blind'.

Comment: If you say, "She is effing and blinding" you mean "She is swearing". If you say "Are you effing blind?", you mean "Are you f@cking blind?" (i.e. Not *literally* blind, but you don't see something or understand something - that I think you should.)

Comment: _Gorblimey_ is indeed related to literal blindness in the sense that it's a corruption of "[May] God blind me", used as an expletive centuries ago.

Comment: @chasly - you can write 'fuck' on here. A recent variant of 'effing and blinding' is 'effing and jeffing'.

Comment: Is the phrase "effing and blinding" reasonably common? I'm an American, but this is the first time I've ever heard it.

Comment: I also have never heard this phrase in my 40 years of American English @TannerSwett

Comment: When you write F-word, do you mean fuck? If so, why do you obfuscate it?

Comment: @RandyL As the Collins dictionary notes, it is a British English expression, not Australian or American.

Comment: @TannerSwett It might not be "common" in the UK simply because most Brits don't go around swearing for no reason. On the other hand the meaning is widely known. It usually implies that somebody is angry and out of control, not just that they are swearing.